# Android tcp client app crash by connection

Tags: java, android, tcp

I develope a simple chat app with login and register.
For the communication I use TCP Client and a TCP Server.
If user click to login I connect to the server.
Now I need to check if connected or not. If returns true I start a new intent.
I don't have rooted android phone to see the logs and my computer is to low for the emulator, but maybe the fail can you see in the source.

If the progress dialog done loaded is the app crash. Maybe I need a Exception..

Login:

```
public void LoginUser() {
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private Context context;

        public AttemptLogin(Activity activity) {
            context = activity;
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.login) + "...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            session = new Session(getBaseContext(), "Azcaq", "Azcaq $$", "Test");
            session.client = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                public void messageReceived(String message) {

                }
            });
            session.client.run();
            Login();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    new AttemptLogin(this).execute();
}

public void Login() {
    if(session.client.isConnected()) {
        session.setLogin(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.connectionfail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

TcpClient

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class TcpClient {
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "82.168.0.198";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 64000;
    private String mServerMessage;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;
    private Boolean connected = false;

    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    public Boolean isConnected() {
        if(connected) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        mRun = false;
        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
        connected = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        mRun = true;
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
            try {
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                if(socket.isConnected()) {
                    connected = true;
                }

                while (mRun) {
                    try {
                        mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                        if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                            mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                        }
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) { } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: Do you can't read my post? I don't have a log.

Comment: may be you are trying to open a socket on port which is already open. you have to post you logcat for better assessment